# How to increment index by 1 every time loop is run?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to increment index by 1 every time loop is run, but I don't know how to do it.

This is the code I have right now :

```
categoryindex = categorylist[1]

while True:
    try:
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20, ignored_exceptions=NoSuchElementException).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[child::span[text()='{oddsnumber}'] and span[text()='{oddstype}']]"))).click()
    except:
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException,)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20, ignored_exceptions=NoSuchElementException).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[text() ='{categoryindex}']"))).click()
```

I want it to start from index [1] until requested element is found. I tried using + increment but I'm not sure how it works with index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for` loop. Also use `break` statement. This will break the loop when the element is found and if not found, it will increment the index and check again in the next iteration.

```
for i in range(1, len(categorylist)):
    categoryindex = categorylist[i]
    try:
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20, ignored_exceptions=NoSuchElementException).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[child::span[text()='{oddsnumber}'] and span[text()='{oddstype}']]"))).click()
      
    except:
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException,)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20, ignored_exceptions=NoSuchElementException).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[text() ='{categoryindex}']"))).click()
```

Comment: The loop is working, but once it gets to page where the element is it doesn't click on it. I copied WebDriverWait(driver, 20, ignored_exceptions=NoSuchElementException).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[child::span[text()='{oddsnumber}'] and span[text()='{oddstype}']]"))).click() and put it outside of the loop and then it does click on the element, but not when it is in the loop

Comment: I think it is because of `break` remove break and try, I Update the answer as well.

Comment: I think I found a problem, but don't know how to fix it. The list is created like this `for category in categories:
    text = category.text
    categorylist.append(text)
    print(text)

time.sleep(5)
categorylist2 = categorylist
categorylist2.remove('Specials')` , the click only doesn't happen on elements on list that are after categorylist2.remove('Specials'), so it goes like Page1(click works), Page2(click works), Page3(click works), Specials(page gets skipped), Page5(click doesn't work), Page6(click doesn't work) etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next()` funtion to do so without using any index. first, you must create an iterator from your iterable. the iterble value is the list you called `categorylist`. to create an iterator from it just use `iter(categorylist)`

Then you can iterate your list by calling `next()` funtion on it. it will return list items from first item to last each time you call it.

example:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
my_list_iterator = iter(my_list)
print(next(my_list_iterator)) #optput:'a'
print(next(my_list_iterator)) #optput:'b'
print(next(my_list_iterator)) #optput:'c'
print(next(my_list_iterator)) #optput:'d'
```

If you call next one more time an exception will be raised as `StopIteration`

 To avoid the error there is two ways:

```
# Way 1: pass second parameter to next() function to be returned if all list items iterated
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
my_list_iterator = iter(my_list)
MY_DEFAULT = 'my_default'
print(next(my_list_iterator, MY_DEFAULT)) #optput:'a'
print(next(my_list_iterator, MY_DEFAULT)) #optput:'b'
print(next(my_list_iterator, MY_DEFAULT)) #optput:'c'
print(next(my_list_iterator, MY_DEFAULT)) #optput:'d'
print(next(my_list_iterator, MY_DEFAULT)) #optput:'my_default'
...
print(next(my_list_iterator, MY_DEFAULT)) #optput:'my_default'

# Way 2: use the funtion next() as many as the list size:
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    print(next(my_list_iterator))
# outputs: prints 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' each one in new line
```

How to use it in your code?

```
categorylist_iterator = iter(categorylist)

next(categorylist_iterator) # iterate the 0th index to start from index 1 in the loop
while True:
    categoryindex = next(categorylist_iterator)
    try:
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20, ignored_exceptions=NoSuchElementException).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[child::span[text()='{oddsnumber}'] and span[text()='{oddstype}']]"))).click()
    except:
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException,)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20, ignored_exceptions=NoSuchElementException).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[text() ='{categoryindex}']"))).click()
```

But how to avoid `StopIteration` error in the code. if the iteration on `categorylist` be ended the error will be raised!

```
DEFAULT_INDEX = 'A value which not exists in the list categorylist. for example it can be a random token'
categorylist_iterator = iter(categorylist)

next(categorylist_iterator) # iterate the 0th index to start from index 1 in the loop
while True:
    categoryindex = next(categorylist_iterator, DEFAULT_INDEX)
    if categoryindex == DEFAULT_INDEX:
        break
    try:
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20, ignored_exceptions=NoSuchElementException).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[child::span[text()='{oddsnumber}'] and span[text()='{oddstype}']]"))).click()
    except:
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException,)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20, ignored_exceptions=NoSuchElementException).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[text() ='{categoryindex}']"))).click()
```